# Can Anyone suggest free font similar to Don Citarella Gothic

Tags: fonts, logo, font-identification

I am stuck in a project which is logo redesigning. Client need fonts *similar* to the existing one.

**The font is  Don Citarella Gothic and it is a paid font.**

I need a look a like font which is free to use.

Can anyone suggest please. It would be great help.

[image: sample font Don Citarella Gothic 1]

[image: sample font Don Citarella Gothic 2]

Comment: Are you being paid for the project?

Comment: Yes I am getting paid for this. But Client need similar font and not want to pay for the font.

Comment: If you're getting paid, why shouldn't the font designer get paid? A font takes a lot of effort to create. If we're purchasing a font for a project we typically just include the cost of the font into the final project price.

Comment: What should I do then. Ask client to drop project or to pay for font??

Comment: You have several ethically acceptable choices: 1) Pay for the font yourself, and remember for next time to include the cost of fonts in your own project costs. 2) Tell the client that they need to pay for the font, which is advantageous because they then have license to use the font in all their branding materials 3) Spend several hours looking for a free font that suits the project brief. Whether the amount of time you spend trying to find a free font is worth more or less to you than the - very reasonable - price of the font is for you to decide.

Comment: The font is $20-40. How much do you value your time? If you spend more time searching for a new font than what your hourly rate is then buy it! But yes, the client could easily pay for this since it's a specific request as much as purchasing stock images; it also depends on what agreement you have with the client and what's the budget for the job. If he/she doesn't buy then you buy it and enjoy having a new font... and put that expense on the next invoice and your tax report :) (And you don't share that font with the client.)

Comment: Thanks for your time to help me out. Thank you so much. You are so right. I did not think that way.. Thanks a lot..

Comment: If you still want to find a similar (not identical) free font, maybe you could post a screenshot of the font and also have a look at this link to see if you can improve your question or use the links there to find your font: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions

Answer (score 1):

[Disco Font](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/DISCO):

[image: Disco Font]If you are still wanting a similar font, this one may work for you. It only has one weight however.

Comment: Would you mind posting a sample image of the font so that it's easier to see upfront?